# how to refresh package.json file after install a new module?

Tags: node.js, npm

when the `package.json` file already exists and then install a new node module,  how to add the new dependency data (module name and version number) to the `package.json` file?

I mean,  not manually. Is there a native method using `npm` ?

Comment: thanks to anwsers, i think it is use`npm init`again ,it will add  all  the dependencies,if forgotten to use`--save `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `npm 5.0.0` the dependancy should be automatically created on the file, prior to this version you must pass option `--save` when doing `npm install` to tell `npm` to write the `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding any module as dependency module in you project, you can use this command `npm install module_name --save` it automatically add in **package.json** file